# How to sort a string starting with numbers in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, tkinter

I have to sort a list to show on a dropdown (tkinter), but the list starts with numbers.

```
tkvar = StringVar(window)
choices = {"1 - Potatos", "2- Tomatos", etc}
```

When I use `sort` I got:

```
1 - Potatos
10 - Something
11 - Something else
2 - Tomatos
```

If I split into number-string pair like:

```
choices = {(1," - Potatos"), (2,"- Tomatos"), etc}
```

In the dropdown it show like this:

```
1{ - Potatos}
2{ - Tomatos}
...
```

Obviously, I don't want the `{}` to be printed.

I want to have the dropdown like:

```
1 - Potatos
2 - Tomatos

tkvar.set('1 - Potatos')

popupMenu = OptionMenu(topFrame, tkvar, *choices)

tkvar.trace('w', change_dropdown)

def change_dropdown(*args):
    print( tkvar.get() )
...
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: The first example is a `set`. You can't sort that directly. Can you please show your actual data structures and code?

Comment: You mention drop-downs, but nothing in your examples shows how you populate them. Please add that in.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sorted` with a `key` argument:

```
l = [
    "1 - Potatos",
    "10 - Something",
    "11 - Something else",
    "2 - Tomatos"
]

for s in sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x.split("-")[0])):
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
1 - Potatos
2 - Tomatos
10 - Something
11 - Something else
```

Comment: Errors:
File "XXXXXXX.py", line 146, in <module>
    for s in sorted(choices, key=lambda x:  int(x.split("-")[0])):
  File "XXXXXXX.py", line 146, in <lambda>
    for s in sorted(choices, key=lambda x: int(x.split("-")[0])):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'

Comment: @AJSilva something is wrong with your `choices` list. check it

Comment: OMG, found the solution...not need for sorts or anything, just make the array with [ ] instead of { }

Comment: `{"1-potato", "2-tomato"}` is a python `set`, while `[..]` is a `list`. be sure you get familiar with them before continuing with your program, you won't regret it

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [natsort](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library. It's a small library that does pretty much what [@Lante's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56154497/2988730) suggests, but in a very detailed way. It separates the numerical and non-numerical portions of strings to sort them in natural order (hence the name).

The simplest way:

```
from natsort import natsorted

choices = natsorted(choices)
```

This doesn't do an in-place sort. To do that, you can generate your own sort key and pass it to `list.sort`:

```
from natsort import natsort_keygen

choices.sort(key=natsort_keygen())
```

I'm not affiliated with natsort in any way, just a satisfied user.

Answer (score 0):

Found a super simple solution.
I was doing:

```
list={"1-a",
      "2-b",
      "3-c"}
```

This prints in any order

just had to change the { } to [ ]

```
list=["1-a",
      "2-b",
      "3-c"]
```

And works great. this prints the exact order of the array.